# OpenCL: How to find out maximum size of Image3D that fits on GPU

Tags: c++, opencl

When using OpenCL one can check the maximum theoretical size of an image3D on a device by calling

> CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH
>   CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_DEPTH
>   CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_HEIGHT

but for example my GPU does not provide enough memory to allocate a 3D RGBA image of that size. So obviously, when I try to push such an image, an OutOfResources error occurs.

**My question:** Given a `vector<float>` which contains an image with dimensions `<2048`, how do I check if it fits on my GPU?

The background of my question is, that I would like to split up the image otherwise in order to process it in parts.

Comment: Should be `CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH`, as well, is it a typo?. 2D may be giving bigger sizes. If you are inside each bound for the size, and the device has enough memory, it should work.

Comment: @DarkZeros Corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` which returns the maximum size of memory object allocation in bytes.

Although this doesn't take into account the currently used memory, you could try to do it yourself by keeping track of the allocations you're doing and checking against `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE`.

Comment: If I have an image of size `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` it will not necessarily fit on the GPU, right? Because even if my kernel only takes this image as an argument there needs to be more memory for local variables etc?

Comment: That's right, and it can be quite different for each device. You really need to try various size allocations and see what works.